# Passing arguments to a function at run-time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the arguments to a function dynamically.
I found a lot of questions on SO on this topic but somewhere I am not getting it.

My problem is very similar to the scenario. I am using square brackets for function name and the arguments, but I am not sure where I am wrong.

It will be great if someone can point me to a good documentation on this.

```
function myage(age) {
    alert("My age is " + age + "!!");
}

model = [{
    name : "Tom",
    age : 30,
    link : myage
},
{
    name : "James",
    age : 32,
    link : myage
}];

var elem;
for(var i = 0; i < model.length ; i++) {
    elem = '<li><a href="#" onclick=[' + model[i].link + '][' + model[i].age + ']>' + model[i].name + '</a></li>';
}
```

It's an error, it doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you using square brackets in `onclick`? Square brackets have to be put after an expression that returns an array or object, to index into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're constructing a string in the `onclick` attribute, the `link` property should be the name of the function, not the function itself. Then you should put the argument in parentheses after it, not square brackets.

```js
function myage(age) {
  alert("My age is " + age + "!!");
}

model = [{
  name: "Tom",
  age: "thirty",
  link: "myage"
}, {
  name: "James",
  age: 32,
  link: "myage"
}];

var elem;
for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
  elem = '<li><a href="#" onclick="' + model[i].link + '(\'' + model[i].age + '\')">' + model[i].name + '</a></li>';
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += elem;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container"></div>
```

However, if you want it to look up the link when the user clicks, you could do this. You need to put the literal `model[i]` in the `onclick` attribute, not the function.

```js
function myage(age) {
    alert("My age is " + age + "!!");
}

model = [{
    name : "Tom",
    age : 30,
    link : myage
},
{
    name : "James",
    age : "thirty-two",
    link : myage
}];

var elem;
for(var i = 0; i < model.length ; i++) {
    elem = '<li><a href="#" onclick="model[' + i + '].link(\'' + model[i].age + '\')">' + model[i].name + '</a></li>';
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += elem;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container"></div>
```

Comment: If in place of the digits as 30 and 32, I write them as strings "Thirty" and "Thirty-Two", should the above code remain the same?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that performs mathematics on the ages, so it doesn't matter if they're strings or numbers.

Comment: If i use digits as 30 and 32, the above code works fine, but with strings, the code starts looking for its value (maybe considering it as a variable). What could be the problem?

Comment: It needs quotes around the argument in the `onclick` attribute, otherwise it will try to use a string as a variable name. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have your indexer in the wrong place. Since 'model' is the array, you should be indexing model. E.g.: `model[i].link`